# Beginner level help in Android.Sqlite and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am new to Android development. I have an Android project and want to modify an SQLite database that is integrated within this project but failed to find the database in my project folder.

Comment: You have to copy you file inside `assets` folder

Comment: Database already has been integrated i just want to know his location.

Answer (score 1):

Where You Find your DB?  find from this `root/Data/Data/<packagename>/databases`...  Use SQLite Manager plugin for Show DB in local Browser.

Comment: I want to find out Db in my Eclips

Comment: than go to Window/Show View/other select FileExproler Click OK .  After that Select Data/Data/<packagename>/database.

Answer (score 0):

DDMS -> select emulator -> data/data/com.yourpakage.name/database/

(or)

parthpatibabdha answer: Window/Show View/other select FileExproler Click OK . After that Select Data/Data/packagename/database

[image]